# JavaScript: change td background color on click (toggling class)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a table of checkbox inputs with the actual check boxes hidden and replaced with clickable labels. As such, I want to change the background color of the table cells on click. (Ideally it'd be tied directly to the checkbox state, but I couldn't figure that out.)

I have no idea why my code doesn't work.

HTML:

```
<table id="workingSetTable" border="1">
<tr>
<td onclick="togglechecked()" class="checked">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
  </div>
</td>
</tr>
```

CSS:

```
input {
    display: none;
}

td {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.checked {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

JS:

```
$(togglechecked() {
    $("td").click(togglechecked() {
        $(this).toggleClass("checked");
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k3jygrnd/2)

Comment: What's `$(togglechecked() {` supposed to do?

Comment: Toggle the background color from blue to red (toggling the "checked" class on and off)

Comment: That's incorrect syntax. You probably want to either make it a function to call, like `function toggleChecked() {...` or an event handler like `$('#workingSetTable td')...`

Comment: Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/k3jygrnd/4/)? Sorry, I don't actually know JS, it's just impossible to do what I'm trying to do with CSS

Comment: Is this what you're after https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ab1ekykr/?

Comment: @DHighland I added a new answer, created completely without javascript. Have a look.

Answer (score 1):

On JS fiddle you didn't select Jquery so it wasnt loaded, and wouldnt have worked no matter what you did.

You also have more syntax than you need. To add a click handler you dont need anything in the html. You dont need a named function either.

https://jsfiddle.net/w45antdo/

this is all the jquery you need (aside from checking the button, which you dont need to do unless you're submitting this as form data to another page)

```
$("td").click(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass("checked");
});
```

If this is somewhere other than jsfiddle, you also should tell it to load the jquery after the html is done, usually by doing

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty example - I use this (with a BIT more bells and whistles) to create on/off shifts for a timesheet-coordination-thing. This does the checkbox thing, and sends data to a background PHP-script that updated the database, etc. etc.

```js
$('.shifts_clickable td').on('click',function() {
       if ($(this).hasClass('registered_active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('registered_active').addClass('not_active');
       } else {
        $(this).removeClass('not_active').addClass('registered_active');
       }
      })
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: initial;
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 98%;
 }
thead, th {
 background: $header-background;
 color: $header-color;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'open_sans_semibold';
 font-size: 1em;
}
td {
 border: 0.1em solid #9a9a9a;
 color: $hilight-contrast;
 font-size: 0.9em;
}
.registered_active {
 background-color: green;
}
.not_active {
 background-color: rgb(220,160,50);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
        <table>
         <thead>
          <tr>
           <th></th><th>Monday</th><th>Tuesday</th><th>Wednesday</th><th>Thursday</th><th>Friday</th><th>Saturday</th></tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody><tr class="shifts_clickable">
           <td class="shift_1_0_heading center"><b>Shift 0</b></td><td id="bar_1__1__0__1" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__0__2" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__0__3" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__0__4" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__0__5" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__0__6" class=" pointer not_active"></td></tr><tr class="shifts_clickable">
           <td class="shift_1_1_heading center"><b>Shift 1</b></td><td id="bar_1__1__1__1" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__1__2" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__1__3" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__1__4" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__1__5" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__1__6" class=" pointer not_active"></td></tr><tr class="shifts_clickable">
           <td class="shift_1_2_heading center"><b>Shift 2</b></td><td id="bar_1__1__2__1" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__2__2" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__2__3" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__2__4" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__2__5" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__2__6" class=" pointer not_active"></td></tr><tr class="shifts_clickable">
           <td class="shift_1_3_heading center"><b>Shift 3</b></td><td id="bar_1__1__3__1" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__3__2" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__3__3" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__3__4" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__3__5" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__3__6" class=" pointer not_active"></td></tr><tr class="shifts_clickable">
           <td class="shift_1_4_heading center"><b>Shift 4</b></td><td id="bar_1__1__4__1" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__4__2" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__4__3" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__4__4" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__4__5" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__4__6" class=" pointer not_active"></td></tr><tr class="shifts_clickable">
           <td class="shift_1_5_heading center"><b>Shift 5</b></td><td id="bar_1__1__5__1" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__5__2" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__5__3" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__5__4" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__5__5" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__5__6" class=" pointer not_active"></td></tr><tr class="shifts_clickable">
           <td class="shift_1_6_heading center"><b>Shift 6</b></td><td id="bar_1__1__6__1" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__6__2" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__6__3" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__6__4" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__6__5" class=" pointer not_active"></td><td id="bar_1__1__6__6" class=" pointer not_active"></td></tr></tbody>
        </table>
        <label for="checkallshifts_1" class="button secondary_button center">Check all shifts for Bar 1</label><input id="checkallshifts_1" name="checkallshifts_1" class="button secondary_button ui-corner-all" type="checkbox">
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsbin.com/teyoziwini/edit?html,css,js,output

The fiddle above shows how to do use labels and hidden check boxes. 
Note that i'm using `visiblity:hidden;` instead of `display:none;` because some browsers (Safari) won't submit form controls that arent' displayed.

HTML

```
  <table id="workingSetTable" border="1">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td >
          <label class="checked">
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
          </label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

CSS

```
.checked {
    background-color: blue;
}

td label {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;  
}

td label.checked {
     background-color: blue;
}

td label input {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;    
}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).on('change', 'label input', function(){
  var $this = $(this);  
  $this.closest('label').toggleClass('checked', $this.prop('checked'));  
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you want.

But I come up with this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/avialle/zykc6gz9/6/

```js
$(function() {
  $('input').click(function (evt) {
    $(evt.target).parent().toggleClass('checked');
  });
});
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
td {
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:20px;
    background-color:white;
}
td.checked {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="checked"><input type="checkbox" checked=""></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td class="checked"><input type="checkbox" checked=""></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example entirely without javascript.

```css
table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 5em;
}
table input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}
label {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input name="input_1_1" id="input_1_1" type="checkbox"><label for="input_1_1">&nbsp;</label></td>
    <td><input name="input_1_2" id="input_1_2" type="checkbox"><label for="input_1_2">&nbsp;</label></td>
    <td><input name="input_1_3" id="input_1_3" type="checkbox"><label for="input_1_3">&nbsp;</label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```